# Is there any way to know if the user pressed "send" or "X" button after the new mail window opened via outlook from powerbuilder?

Tags: email, powerbuilder, ole, outlook-2007

Is there any way to know if the user pressed "send" or "X" button after the new mail window opened via outlook from powerbuilder? I want to pop up a message after "send" or "X" were pressed. The compose email mechanism is created using OLE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but if you are using OLE you might want to look at the methods provided in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).  Quite often you can use them as well as object properties within PowerScript.  There might be some type of 'flag' indicating if the message was sent or similar.